# Installing J2ME Wireless Toolkit No Suitable Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: java

I have downloaded and installed JavaSE, JavaEE, and Netbeans yet when I try to install the Sun Java Wireless Tookit 2.5.2 for CLDC I get this error:

The directory that you have chosen does not include a suitable Java (TM) Virtual Machine.

and the directory it points to is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23

What is the deal? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Virtual Machine refers to the Java Runtime Environment (JRE)

I see that you said you downloaded JavaSE but which one?

JDK has the Dev Kit and the JRE. JRE is just the run-time environment.

Comment: +1! To put it more clearly, JRE from JDK is not used by normal programs. They need traditional JRE installed.

Comment: I have this package installed https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u23-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer

Comment: I have both the JRE and JDK installed. Still same error :(

Comment: Since you have both you may need to set a Path. It should point to C:\whatever dir\jre-you-want-to-use\bin